# Redirect to special link with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a issue with my domain.

How can i automatic redirect from `site.com` to `site.com/manager` with WebServer `NGINX`

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration, replacing `example.com` with your url

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  examle.com;
    location / {
        return 301 http://examle.com/manager$request_uri;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attention my question

I have been check but this link `example.com` retrurn `examle.com/manager/manager/manager/manager/manager/manager/manager/manager/manager` 

Then it's maybe not success with me.

Comment: @Uncelvel, yes, that is a reasonable comment. I've fixed suggested solution. This should not cause an infinite redirect